# How to enable code completion for namespaced annotations in Netbeans 8.0?

Tags: netbeans, doctrine-orm, annotations, zend-framework2, code-completion

I'm working with Netbeans 8.0 on a Zend Framework 2 project with Doctrine integration.

I want to use the IDE's code completion feature when typing "namespaced" Doctrine annotations in entity classes.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/** @ORM\Entity **/
class User {}
```

Doctrine 2 support is activated for this project an doctrine.bat is set in the doctrine settings.

Does anyone know how to activate code completion for the @ORM "namespace"?

Comment: have you read the netbeans docs? https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-code-completion.html

Comment: I googled this matter a lot and found some NB Testsuites confirming that this feature (namespaced Annotations) is already implemented in Netbeans. So I didn't think about writing it by myself...

Comment: any clue how to auto complete `@ORM\*`

Answer (score 0):

I just activated the ORM code completion

To activate doctrine 2 go install the doctrine then go to netbeans options -> php > Frameworks and tools -> doctrine 2->give the doctrine.bat path

Then goto project properties and Frameworks enable doctrine.

I was able to get Symfony command execute via netbeans but not the doctrine.

For additional information refer following links.

- https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/screencast-doctrine2.html
- https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/doctrine2_support_added